# Using UserManager within a Linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use UserManager within a Linq query as per the example below...

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

var query = (from f in db.Features
             join u in userManager.Users on f.UserId equals u.Id
             where u.UserName.Contains("Smith")
             select f).ToList();
```

But this results in an error message...

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

The only way I can think of resolving this issue is to use a SQL query using `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is db? I assume it's another dbContext. You shouldn't have 2 db contexts, instead inherit IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> and add your dbSets in it.

Comment: @Medo well, you can have multiple contexts, only you wouldn't be able to do cross-context queries in LINQ.

Comment: I said shouldn't :) For this question I would stick with my original answer and suggest you "merge" two dbContexts into one. If you really wanna have 2 dbContexts you can query userIds and use that result to query features

Comment: @Medo Sorry, I just copied `dbContext` from somewhere else. For me it would be `db.Database.SqlQuery` as I have `db` set up as `public ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();'   I only have one context.

Comment: That application dbContext should contain user table if that's how you set it up